# Why doesn't css 100% - 100% work without absolute?

Tags: jquery, html, css

question 1) I have this **http://jsfiddle.net/Qx9uG/1/** working with absolute. When I remove the absolute, **http://jsfiddle.net/Qx9uG** it doesn't work. Why is that?

question 2) why do I get no result if I change width from % to px and height px to % ?

**http://jsfiddle.net/SGpb2/2/** vs. **http://jsfiddle.net/SGpb2/1/**

```
.box
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `100%` of `0` is also `0`.

Define the parent elements, in this case `body`/`html`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/PHhE9/)

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

The reason it works with absolute positioning is because absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the flow of the document, thus their parent's dimensions don't need to be defined.

Comment: @thenewseattle it already been said 100% is 0 , means `.box` % varies on it's parent element